# JavaScript promise and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have a simple Node.js server in which I'm trying to use a Node.js package called [image-similarity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-similarity), according to its doc it is used like this:

```
let  imageSimilarity  = require ('image-similarity') ; 
imageSimilarity('./image/1.jpg', './image/2.jpg').then ( res =>  { 
    console.log(res) ; // The  similarity is 0.8162515507509954 
} ) ;
```

It works fine like that but I'm trying to use it inside an HTTP Node.js server, like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var imageSimilarity = require('image-similarity');

http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});

    var result = "";

    imageSimilarity('./images/1.png', './images/2.png').then(res => {
        result = res;
    });

    res.end(result);
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I just need to add the result to the response, but I found that I cannot access the `res` variable from inside the then `function`, and I cannot simply assign the result to a variable like in the previous example since that block is executed asynchronously it will simply be empty when I try to use it outside.

Comment: use `then()` for `result` as far as imageSimilarity is async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into problems with it being async, you need to call `res.end(result)` from within your `then()`

```
var http = require('http');
var imageSimilarity = require('image-similarity');

http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});

    imageSimilarity('./images/1.png', './images/2.png').then(result => {
        res.end(result);
    });


}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

also I note I renamed the `then`'s argument to `result` to avoid naming clashes with the outer `res`